# Create new column for a pandas dataframe inside a for loop

Tags: pandas

There is a pandas dataframe with 3 columns A,B and C

```
Id  Date        Latitude     Longitude
9497        2017-03-03  44.149147   -70.230300
914         2017-02-27  38.832256   -104.761086
```

I want to loop through the dataframe and create a new column inside a for loop.

I tried with the below code but I get the error "column not defined". Any advice would be really helpful.

```
for index,row in df2.iterrows():
  value = Geohash.encode(row['Latitude'],row['Longitude'], precision=8)
  df2.set_value(index,'Geohash',value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the column before your loop:

```
df2['Geohash'] = -1 # or np.nan or whatever

for index,row in df2.iterrows():
      value = Geohash.encode(row['Latitude'],row['Longitude'], precision=8)
      df2.set_value(index,'Geohash',value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I try with this, I get the error "invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'dry51v5g' "

Comment: Using [.assign](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) might be a better way to do this.